# To what color does "fg = 248" correspond in Ranger's color schemes?

Tags: python, themes, colors

I'm trying out [Ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) file manager written in Python because it has very nice file and image preview features.

While four color schemes are provided by default, others can be added by the user to *~/.config/ranger/colorschemes* as *.py* files.

My question concerns the color values. For example, a bit of code taken from the [Zenburn theme](http://dotshare.it/dots/706/) has:

```
        if context.border:
            fg = 248
```

Is there a source that explains values such as *248* in terms of RGB or hex code?

By changing the *context.border* color from *248*, which is a light gray, to other values, I figured out that *123* is like *aquamarine*, *55* is like *violet*, *5* appears to be *magenta* and *1* is *red*.

I couldn't find any clues in [X11 color names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) or [Web colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors).

Comment: I'm looking for a published table like what I've linked to. I couldn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

This [vimporn link](https://www.reddit.com/r/vimporn/comments/aq6voi/changed_my_color_scheme_every_week_cos_i_was/egdyfb8) led me to [256 Colors - Cheat Sheet - Xterm, HEX, RGB, HSL](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/).

[image: XTerm Colors]

Comment: Anothr good read into for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue